# Get id of elem changed when event is attached to document

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, event-capturing

Points to be noted:

- The **whole** document is `content editable`
- The body has an `input event` attached to it
- I need to get the id of the **specific** element which was changed
- Only **vanilla** Javascript is allowed

*e.g* : If I change `Tom` to Paul, I should get `m1` as id.

*Problem*: `e.target` returning the *body* element instead *specifc* element(`div#m1`)

```js
document.body.contentEditable = true;
document.body.addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

```html
<div id="m1">Hello Tom</div>
<div id="m2">Hello Sam</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A problem is - if the whole body is editable, how do you know what elements will remain, or be removed altogether, or even added, when your user starts editing?

Is it acceptable to you to have each of the different elements marked as editable independently? As per the snippet below.

```js
document.getElementById('m1').contentEditable = true;
document.getElementById('m2').contentEditable = true;

document.body.addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

```html
<div id="m1">Hello Tom</div>
<div id="m2">Hello Sam</div>
```

It's also possible to set each element editable using a loop of course, to not repeat code and to adapt to different document structures automatically.

Comment: This could be a suggestion but solution.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in my scenario, only the whole body is content editable and I need to reach its elements

Answer (score 0):

I have added `e.target.id` in your console. Hope this works for you

```js
document.body.contentEditable = true;
document.body.addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(e.target.id);
})
```

```html
<div id="m1">Hello Tom</div>
<div id="m2">Hello Sam</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `e.target` is returning the body and I need the exact `div element`

Comment: I have checked, It will return the element where the change has been made. Are you updating these elements? because if you try the same code in the browser console. say do in the same stack overflow tab and try typing in the above search then you will get the search element ID currently it is blank in this case

Comment: Yes, blank in case of stackoverflow. because the search box is not having id

Comment: Why is the id blank if I am not updating the elements even in my text editor?

Comment: What do you mean by updating element? changing the values of element OR element itself ?